# JavaFX WebView/WebEngine printing ignores background

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I am using JavaFX 8 WebView to render and print web pages. I have noticed that when using the `WebEngine.print()` method, the printed output ignores any background styling in the HTML.

Is this by design? Is there a way to get the printed output to include background styling? There appears to be ways in other WebKit platforms to enable this (for example [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebPreferences_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebPreferences/setShouldPrintBackgrounds%3A)) but I can't see an equivalent for JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, the solution is to use the -wekbit-print-color-adjust CSS property:

```
    document.body.style.webkitPrintColorAdjust = "exact";
```